# Build Chromium failed (ensure_bootstrap: command not found)

Tags: chromium-os

I tried to get the chromiumos source code and would like to built the chromiumos.

```
export BOARD=coral
./setup_board --board=${BOARD} --force
./build_packages --board=${BOARD}
```

But after the commands finished, i got some ERROR message, and I also try to update depot_tools but seems limited by permission denied...How can I solve it?
Thanks!

----Message

```
(cr) ((8c78090...)) ft@ft-Swift-SF315-51 ~/trunk/src/scripts $ ./setup_board --board=${BOARD} --force
INFO    : Updating chroot
INFO    : Clearing shadow utils lockfiles under /
INFO    : Updating cross-compilers
10:34:40: INFO: Determining required toolchain updates...
10:34:41: INFO: Nothing to update!
INFO    : Bootstrapping depot_tools
/mnt/host/source/src/scripts/update_chroot: line 90: ensure_bootstrap: command not found
ERROR   :    5 10:34:41 CST 2018
ERROR   :  PGID  PPID   PID     ELAPSED     TIME %CPU COMMAND
ERROR   :     8     4     8  1-20:51:43 00:00:00  0.0 -bash
ERROR   : 27470     8 27470       00:01 00:00:00  4.0  \_ /bin/bash ./setup_board --board=coral --force
ERROR   : 27470 27470 27656       00:01 00:00:00  2.0      \_ /bin/bash /mnt/host/source/src/scripts/update_chroot --toolchain_boards=coral --usepkg
ERROR   : 27470 27656 27786       00:00 00:00:00  0.0          \_ /bin/bash /mnt/host/source/src/scripts/update_chroot --toolchain_boards=coral --usepkg
ERROR   : 27470 27786 27787       00:00 00:00:00  0.0              \_ ps f -o pgid,ppid,pid,etime,cputime,%cpu,command
ERROR   : Arguments of 27656:  '--toolchain_boards=coral' '--usepkg'
ERROR   : Backtrace:  (most recent call is last)
ERROR   :  update_chroot:90:main(), called: die_err_trap  
ERROR   : 
ERROR   : Command failed:
ERROR   :   Command 'ensure_bootstrap' exited with nonzero code: 127
ERROR   :    5 10:34:41 CST 2018
ERROR   :  PGID  PPID   PID     ELAPSED     TIME %CPU COMMAND
ERROR   :     8     4     8  1-20:51:43 00:00:00  0.0 -bash
ERROR   : 27470     8 27470       00:01 00:00:00  4.0  \_ /bin/bash ./setup_board --board=coral --force
ERROR   : 27470 27470 27800       00:00 00:00:00  0.0      \_ /bin/bash ./setup_board --board=coral --force
ERROR   : 27470 27800 27801       00:00 00:00:00  0.0          \_ ps f -o pgid,ppid,pid,etime,cputime,%cpu,command
ERROR   : Arguments of 27470: ./setup_board '--board=coral' '--force'
ERROR   : Backtrace:  (most recent call is last)
ERROR   :  setup_board:93:main(), called: die_err_trap  
ERROR   : 
ERROR   : Command failed:
ERROR   :   Command '"${SRC_ROOT}/scripts"/update_chroot ${UPDATE_ARGS}' exited with nonzero code: 1
ERROR   :   (Note bash sometimes misreports "command not found" as exit code 1 instead of 127)
```

---

Answer (score 1):

you need to make sure depot_tools is in your $PATH at all times, including before you enter the sdk with `cros_sdk`

once inside the sdk, depot_tools is mounted at `/mnt/host/depot_tools/` which should also be in your $PATH

Comment: I have two `depot_tools` dirs inside the sdk, I have to add `/mnt/host/source/depot_tools` to the $PATH to have the above command